# [Dialogflow]Update Permission through Webhook format (for push notifications)

Tags: php, webhooks, dialogflow-es

**ORIGINAL REQUEST:** I'm trying to implement the push notifications following the documentation: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications

I'm using Dialogflow with webhooks (in PHP) and the documentation is giving example in nodeJS

Right now, i'm blocked because of the Update permission, here's my Webhook response :

```
{
"source": "webhook",
"payload": {
    "google": {
        "expectUserResponse": true,
        "systemIntent": {
            "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
            "data": {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
                "permissions": [
                    "UPDATE"
                ]
            },
            "updatePermission": {
                "intent": "notification.simple.text"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I do the simulation, asks me a permission for a push, but not for the intent I specified.

I'm quiet sure that the problem is the updatePermission, something must be wrong with that:
 Is it the field name? 
In intent, i put the intent name that i filled in dialogflow, maybe do i have to an use action? Is it in the good format ?

If someone can help me or just give me an example of a clean response for an update permission.

Thanks!

**Solution**

I just found why, my json wasn't good, the updatePermissionValueSpec must be into data object.

```
{
"source": "webhook",
"payload": {
    "google": {
        "expectUserResponse": true,
        "systemIntent": {
            "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
            "data": {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
                "permissions": [
                    "UPDATE"
                ],
                "updatePermissionValueSpec": {
                    "intent": "notification_simple_text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by 'it ask me a permission for a push, but not for the intent I specified'? Does it ask for permission using a completely different intent? Can you better describe the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Generally when asking to send push notifications it will display the content title (not the intent name) that you provided in the Action Console at the time of enabling push notifications for that specific intent.

Comment: Hey, I'm developing such kind of functionality in Python, I've asked for the permission for notification but now I want to know how to send a push notification. Can you please show me the JSON response or code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `updatePermission` should be named `updatePermissionValueSpec`.

Example response:

```
"payload": {
  "google": {
    "expectUserResponse": true,
    "richResponse": {
      "items": [
        {
          "simpleResponse": {
            "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "systemIntent": {
      "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
      "data": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
        "permissions": [
          "UPDATE"
        ],
        "updatePermissionValueSpec": {
          "intent": "intent_name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i've seen that and tried that, but not working.

Maybe i'm wrong in the "intent_name" ? What is the intent name? Is it the title when we create the dialogflow intent? Or maybe there's a specific format as we have for the context or the sessions (since the V2) ?

Comment: AFAIK, this should be the Dialogflow intent name (the title you use when creating the intent in Dialogflow).

Comment: Okey, so i've tried with updatePermissionValueSpec and the intent name set correctly, but still, in the debug response, the updatePermissionValueSpec is missing and it's always asking me a push authorization for an intent that doesn't correspond to the one I put.

Comment: OK, found it, i updated the original post, thank you for your help  @taylor-caldwell :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Hey, I'm developing such kind of functionality in Python, I've asked for the permission for notification but now I want to know how to send a push notification. Can you please show me the JSON response or code.