# Actions on Google - Push Notifications in C#

Tags: push-notification, actions-on-google

I am trying to get a basic push notification sent to my Action.

I am getting an access token as such

```
    private static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenFromJsonKeyAsync(string jsonKeyFilePath, params string[] scopes)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(jsonKeyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            return await GoogleCredential
                .FromStream(stream) // Loads key file  
                .CreateScoped(scopes) // Gathers scopes requested  
                .UnderlyingCredential // Gets the credentials  
                .GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(); // Gets the Access Token  
        }
    }
```

which returns me an access token.

I am then sending the following notification message

```
{
    "customPushMessage": {
        "userNotification":{
            "title":"Notification Title"
        },
        "target":{
             "userId":"ID_FROM_UPDATES_USER_ID",
             "intent":"Notification Intent",
             "locale":"en-US"
        }
    }
}
```

using the following code

```
        try
        {
            var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenFromJsonKeyAsync("key.json", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation");

            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(proactiveMessage);
            var payload = "{\"customPushMessage\": " + serialized + "}";

            // Wrap our JSON inside a StringContent which then can be used by the HttpClient class
            var httpContent = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

            var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send", httpContent);

            Debug.WriteLine(httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode ? "Successfully sent notification message." : $"Failed to send notification message with {httpResponseMessage.StatusCode}.");

            return httpResponseMessage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Alexa API Service: Failed to send notification message with exception: {ex.Message}");
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

The response code I get is a 403 Forbidden.

I am not sure if the Access Token code is incorrect, the notification structure is incorrect, or if I am missing something else.

Comment: Is there any body on the response code? Sometimes (tho not always), there is a JSON body that gives further information. And just for giggles, try "Bearer" with a capital B.

Comment: I had two issues. One was I didn't have the proper permission payload (was missing (used this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725790/dialogflowupdate-permission-through-webhook-format-for-push-notifications/50729007 - to fix that issue).

The second was the 'b' in bearer.

Now I am receiving a 200 response when I send the notification, however, i am not actually receiving the notification on my phone.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Since we've gotten past the auth error, I would suggest that you ask this as a new question with details about how you've gotten permission, what you're currently sending, and what is happening.

Comment: It also isn't clear how you fixed your other issue - I suggest you post it as a detailed answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: Thanks NiteLordz and @Prisoner got the push notification quickly working from C# webhook thanks to the instructions in this page. However, the User experience is quite miserable. The notification arrive on my phone silently, a microscopic icon on top, invisible on the lock screen, you have to swipe down to see and click it. Any way to improve the alert? These vocal apps are supposed to be used while driving or cooking, such a notification is useless. Better to ask my user to periodically check by voice "Any news for me?". Come on Google, you can do better... Any thoughts / advices?

Answer (score 2):

The token type needs to be "Bearer" with a capitol B. So that line should be

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not requesting permission properly.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725790/dialogflowupdate-permission-through-webhook-format-for-push-notifications/50729007) provided the missing piece of the puzzle for me.

Needed the

```
        "updatePermission": {
            "intent": "notification.simple.text"
        }
```